# loading jQuery UI removes my Google map?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3

I have a wordpress (buddypress) "blog" which is using a google map.  I have the map loading fine using an initialize function which creates a map, then a jQuery .show within the document ready function to add the map to the correct div.

When i load the jQuery UI library the map no longer shows.  I have no idea where to even begin trouble shooting.

Relevant JS:  http://jsfiddle.net/cRkxZ/

Comment: Can you post code or build a JsFiddle, please?

Comment: Where is the HTML that you're using? More information you write and better we can help you...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cRkxZ/3/  Updated with HTML, never used JsFiddle so i'm not sure how to get the map to show there.  If I use this code with only jQuery, the map displays,  enqueue jQuery UI and the map does not display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/cRkxZ/6/

Restore back your options and it should work.

Comment: Thanks,  That doc load was the first thing i ever did in jQuery, and i was thinking it looked fairly odd

Comment: Pay attention putting inside your options and you will never have problems.